# Как вызвать dispose у двух обьетов,если один зависит от другого и не раньше того?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

Есть класс UnitOfWork

```
public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
{
    _context = context;

    _repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}


protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!_disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
    }
    _disposed = true;
}

~UnitOfWork()
{
    Dispose(false);
}
```

Как сделать так,чтобы dispose у DbContext вызывался  вместе с UnitOfWork dispose и не раньше,если в данном примере вызывается dispose несколько раз?

```
private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork,u2;

public  HomeController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,IUnitOfWork u2)
{
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    this.u2 = u2;
    var a = u2 == unitOfWork;
   // ((UnitOfWork)u2).Dispose();
    var u3 = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();
    var b = (u2== u3);
}


public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var users = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<User>();
    var user=new User(){Login = "ДДД",Password = "ДД"};
    users.Create(user);
    await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
    var newUser = await users.GetByIdAsync(1);
    newUser.Login = "Atikin";
    await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();           
    users.Update(newUser);
    await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();

    return View();
}
```

**UnityConfig.cs**

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<DbContext, DiagramSharingContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork,UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

Comment: Не вызывать `context.Dispose()` в других местах.

Comment: @Igor так я и не вызываю вроде ,или я что-то не понимаю здесь?

Comment: @Nikita у вас контейнер вызывает Dispose и у контекста, и у UoW. Если это не вызвает реальных проблем - просто игнорируйте.

Comment: @Nikita т.е. у вас внешнее управление временем жизни. Нет необходимости вызвать context.Dispose() в коде UoW. И вообще нет необходимости реализовать IDisposable в вашем UnitOfWork.

Comment: @PashaPash Так оно несколько раз создает и удаляет контекст,а мне необходимо,что бы один раз создало и один раз удалило.

Comment: @Nikita один раз в пределах чего? вообще ровно один раз за время жизни приложения?

Comment: @PashaPash в пределах жизни unitOfWork

Comment: @Nikita тогда UoW должен и создавать контекст (напрямую или через фабрику), и уничтожать его

Comment: Так а почему нельзя через UOW?

Comment: @Nikita по приложению смотрите. Если ваш контекст создаётся только один раз для UOW и после ненадобности UOW контекст так же не нужен, то уничтожайте объект только в Dispose(bool), как сейчас у вас и больше не трогайте. Если контекст после нужен, то не трогайте его в UOW вообще. Если в общем случае смотреть, то вызов Dispose несколько раз не вызовет проблем, потому что этот метод отрабатывает по факту только один раз, а в остальные разы вхолостую прогоняет.